# How to parse data inside XML?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, odoo-14

any idea how to parse this kind of record? This record has data on it.

```
       <record id="1" model="custom.model>
            <field name="name">Create</field>
            <field name="email_from">dummy@mail.com</field>
            <field name="email_to">todummy@mail.com</field>
            <field name="email_subject">Create new company</field>
            <field name="email_body">
                <![CDATA[
                <record>
                    <field name="process">Create</field>
                    <field name="model">res.company</field>
                    <field name="name">XYZ Company</field>
                    <field name="currency_id">base.USD</field>
                </record>
                ]]>
            </field>
            <field name="email_read">False</field>
        </record>
```

Comment: Hello, would answers from this question be any help to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. I am looking for how to read the cdata so that I know how to put it on records automatically

Comment: Are you looking for the information inside the `CDATA` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for the data inside `CDATA` the code below finds this section and parse it as xml.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<record id="1" model="custom.model">
            <field name="name">Create</field>
            <field name="email_from">dummy@mail.com</field>
            <field name="email_to">todummy@mail.com</field>
            <field name="email_subject">Create new company</field>
            <field name="email_body">
                <![CDATA[
                <record>
                    <field name="process">Create</field>
                    <field name="model">res.company</field>
                    <field name="name">XYZ Company</field>
                    <field name="currency_id">base.USD</field>
                </record>
                ]]>
            </field>
            <field name="email_read">False</field>
        </record>'''
outer_root = ET.fromstring(xml)
email = outer_root.find('.//field[@name="email_body"]')
inner_root = ET.fromstring(email.text)
for field in inner_root.findall('field'):
  print(f'{field.attrib["name"]} -> {field.text}')
```

output

```
process -> Create
model -> res.company
name -> XYZ Company
currency_id -> base.USD
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse XML document:

- Import `xml.dom.minidom`.
- Use the function `parse` to parse the document: `doc=xml.dom.minidom.parse(file name)`.
- Call the list of XML tags from the XML document using code: `doc.getElementsByTagName(“name of xml tags”)`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you parse the outer document with an XML parser in the normal way, navigate to the field with `name="email_body"`, extract the string value of that element, and then pass that string to a new XML parser to be parsed again, to get the inner document.